# How to wrap a c/c++ file into node.js file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a c++ header file. I need to wrap c++ and node.js and use the JS script for my testing. I am new to node.js and I need some help in understanding from where to start. From the analyzing i did so far it seems like we need to manually write the node.js file for calling the function (kind of declaring the functions and use it).

I have created a .js file and declared all my functions and variables in it and called the C++ API.

**var testlib = ffi.Library(file.libtest,{ 'Test_pgm': ['int', ['int','string']] });**

**var result=testlib.test_pgm(20,"name");**

Is there anyway to automate this process so that when i pass the C++ header file it should parse the functions and variables like above and should create output file, so that i can call the C++ Api's directly by importing the output node.js wrapper file.

Previously i have did python and c wrapping using CFFI. There i create a customized header file and passed that file to cffi. Is there anything similar to this method in node.js ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you try yet please mention

Comment: @Akhilesh, I have created a .js file and declared all my functions and variables in it and called the C++ API.

var testlib = ffi.Library(file.libtest,{
 'Test_pgm': ['int', ['string','string','int','string','string','string','string',ERRCODEPtr]]
});

Comment: please post in your Question

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html . Your question is extremely unclear, please add some code in the body of the question and an example of what you would like to do.

Comment: @juandemarco i have already take a look at it. But i am not clear on what it exactly does. sorry for that. what should we give in init function ? I have more than 100 functions in my C++ file. how should i make that expose to node.js file ? Can you please explain

Comment: If your objective is to wrap a complex library with 3 lines of code I'm sorry to say that I don't think that's possible. NodeJS allows you to create bindings between JS and C++, but it's up to you to specify how EACH function is called. Maybe try with something simpler to understand how C++ modules are made for NodeJS, then go back to your lib!

Comment: @juandemarco I am loading a dll and using that dll i am calling the API. (at abi level). Now when i build the ADDONS it acts like a DLL. Now how can i call the API through my previous DLL. It gives me error when i try to call the API through my DLL or through ADDON.

**var testlib = ffi.Library(file.libtest,{ 'Test_pgm': ['int', ['int','string']] });**

when i Used like above, while loading dll declaring the functions it works. (libtest is my path of DLL).